# Incorrect local axis (or something) when importing FBX motion capture

Tags: rigging, bones, rigify, motion-capture, .fbx

I would like to make a few adjustments to a motion capture that I had downloaded, but I found that when I import the FBX file into Blender the bones does not connect correctly as seen in the screen shot.

[image]

If it was just a matter of swapping axis and would have just locally rotate all the bones, but it seems like each bones rotation is different so I have to manually rotate each bone one by one unless there is an easier way to fix this mess?